# Adjust div width according to child element

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7d84Laxr/1/

```
<div class="textCenter">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="inputNoBorder">
        <p style="display: inline-block;">/Some Text.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to underline (`border-bottom`) the `input` and `p` only. But as the width of parent div is same as window width, it draws a full line.

How can I reduce wrapper div's width to only contain two elements so that border will be only below those two elements?

I prefer no JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` to the parent div

```css
.textCenter{
  text-align : center;
}

.inputNoBorder{
 border: 0px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0rem 0.2rem;
  width: 15rem; 
}

.wrapper{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="textCenter">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="inputNoBorder">
  <p style="display: inline-block;">/DENSPRI, LLC.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it did work. Thank you. A little explanation if you can please!

Comment: @SurajS
block elements takes full width of its parent, whether its a normal HTML element or Body or HTML itself. They are kind of rude and say, hey from here to the end of this element the whole width belongs to me.
So the width of your element was going full to the end,

 but inline-block elements are polite one, they say lets share this width, you can be my side, and I will take the only width which how much my content width is.

So its working like this.. I hope you understood.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `.wrapper`

```
width:fit-content;
margin: 0 auto;
```

That way it conforms to the width of the input and paragraph and it's centered. Note the wrapper is still a block so it will not share space side-by-side with another element which an inline-block would do. BTW the input had `display:inline-box` it's fixed to `inline-block`.

```css
.textCenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.inputNoBorder {
  border: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0rem 0.2rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

.wrapper {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="textCenter">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="inputNoBorder">
    <p style="display: inline-block;">/DENSPRI, LLC.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IE-11 does not support `width:fit-content1`

Comment: IE11 has 7 more months before Microsoft kicks it to the curb.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing by Flex, and try the commented property for content horizontal alignment

and Yes please use label in place of P tag, I think that would be more suitable for you and semantic also.

```css
.textCenter{
  text-align : center;
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: flex-end; */
  /* justify-content: center; */
}

.inputNoBorder{
 border: 0px;
  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0rem 0.2rem;
  width: 15rem; 
}

.wrapper{
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="textCenter">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="inputNoBorder">
  <p style="display: inline-block;">/DENSPRI, LLC.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```